# python check for either n out of m methods return value is true

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have written 5 methods which do some stuffs and will return `True` or `False` based on the stuffs. By calling those method I will assign the return value to separate variables and I want to compare those return values and if 5 out of 3 methods return True then I have to do some other stuffs else different stuffs.

```
def method1():
   # stuffs
   return True

def method2():
   #stuffs
   return False

def method3():
   #stuffs
   return True

def method4():
   #stuffs
   return True

def method5():
   #stuffs
   return True 

var1 = method1()
var2 = method2()
var3 = method3()
var4 = method4()
var5 = method5()
```

now I have to do comparison for these variable values and out of 3 are True then have to do some stuffs.

I found `not()` or `any()` in if statements but that is not suitable for my situation. So is there any other function which will help me to take it forward?

Looking for generic way which should work on python 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store teh result of all your methods in a list.
Count the number of True!

```
if [method1(),method2(),method3(),method4(),method5()].count(True) == n:
    pass
```

This should do!
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

How about use

`results = [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5]
if len(v for v in results if v) >= 3:
    ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can add those variables into a list and use [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) (True = 1, False = 0).

```
if sum([var1, var2, var3, var4, var5]) >= 3:
    #do stuffs
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of solving your problem:

```
values = [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5]
if values.count(True) >= 3:
    # do something
```

I think this approach is easy to reason about, which is why I stayed away from multiple list comprehensions.

Happy coding!